# ReactJS - Pegar constante exportada

Tags: react

Eu criei um componente que exporta o axios:

```js
import axios from "axios";
const token = 'Z31XC52XC4';

export default axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://xxxxx.xxxxx.com.br/api/',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'Access-Origin': 'D',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjIzMDEyOSwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cDovL3dlYi1zZXJ2aWNlcy55ZWFwcHMuY29tLmJyL2FwaS91c2Vycy9sb2dpbiIsImlhdCI6MTU1ODU0OTIxMCwiZXhwIjoxNTU5NzU4ODEwLCJuYmYiOjE1NTg1NDkyMTAsImp0aSI6ImxOeDlJNmpWWnFWU1NaeVIifQ.WfayLZMLfGRUwoH2LfBhDWgX4soiISrGxr7lZDZOYUA',
        'Company-Token': token
    }
});
```

Do outro lado eu preciso pegar essa constante chamada token:

```js
import api from '../src/components/Util/api.js';
const token = api.token; ?????
```

Alguem poderia me falar como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 1):

Para importar algo você precisa exportar primeiro:

```
export const token = 'Z31XC52XC4';
```

Antes de mostrar como importar, vale a pena explicar dois tipos de importação. 
A primeira é a `default`( que é a que você está usando). Para poder usa-la você precisa ter um `export default`. Ela é única, ou seja, não posso ter dois `export default` em um código. E quando for importar, você não precisa colocar o mesmo nome que foi declarado.

A outra exportação/importação é a "comum" você exporta como o exemplo que dei acima e importar usando um par de chaves`{}`. Nesse caso, o nome do export tem que ser o mesmo do import.

No seu caso fica assim:

```
import api, { token } from '../src/components/Util/api.js';
```

Agora você pode usar o `token` normalmente.

Obs.: Como demonstrado utilizando seu código, é possível ter os dois tipos de export em um único arquivo.